# How to use the onItemSelectedListener to change the color of a View

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't seem to workout how to get the onItemSelectedListender interface to work. I want to change the color of the item that is selected and then change it back once it is unselected. I've done a bit of reading and I've managed to do something similar a while back with the onItemSelectedListener.

My code is

```
libraryGrid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            //I want to change the color of the view that was just selected
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            adapterView.getSelectedView().setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            //How do I access the view that was just unselected to change it's color?
            adapterView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Null value exception on setbackgroundcolor. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep the track of selected item and change the background of that item from getView method..

Try it this way..

```
libraryGrid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

             mSelectedItem = position;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

and in yout getView method set the background color of selected Item.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            //set Selected color as background on view
        }
        else{
           //set unSelected color as background on View
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had a gridView of textViews. Turns out clicking on a textView isn't counted as a selection. So in my case I need to use onItemClickListener not onItemSelectedListener, in which case I need to record the state like you said. Cheers